# How do I make FastNoise Lite work properly?

Tags: c#, noise, perlin-noise

I'm making a game that will use terrain generation, so I am using the C# version of the [FastNoise Lite](https://github.com/Auburn/FastNoiseLite) library. However, it doesn't seem to be working as I want it to.

I have the following code which generates the TileMap:

```cs
public void Generate(int mapSeed, Vector2 mapSize)
        {
            noise = new FastNoiseLite(mapSeed);
            noise.SetNoiseType(FastNoiseLite.NoiseType.Perlin);
            
            noise.SetFrequency(0.01f);
            noise.SetFractalLacunarity(2f);
            noise.SetFractalGain(0.5f);

            arrMap = new Tile[(int)mapSize.Y, (int)mapSize.X];

            for (int y = 0; y < mapSize.Y; y++)
                for (int x = 0; x < mapSize.X; x++)
                {
                    if (noise.GetNoise(x, y) <= 0.04)
                        arrMap[y, x] = new Water(new Vector2(x, y), gridSize, textures[0]);
                    else if (noise.GetNoise(x, y) <= 0.08)
                        arrMap[y, x] = new Sand(new Vector2(x, y), gridSize, textures[1]);
                    else
                        arrMap[y, x] = new Grass(new Vector2(x, y), gridSize, textures[2]);
                }            
        }
```

All this does is create a 2D array with some different tiles (like water or grass).

Then when I create it and draw it, I get the following result:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUZbn.jpg)

However, I want to have something similar to:

[This](https://preview.redd.it/r0rx9e5de9z41.png?width=500&format=png&auto=webp&s=fe9181cf1d8b8692e3bf2299801e754c09433f27)

The problem is that: when I change the lacunarity or the gain, nothing happens. Frequency just changes how many "patches" of grass there are. I suppose this is a problem with the library and/or the fact I don't know how to use it properly, as I've done this in python before but never got this bug.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All I needed to do was add a fractal type:

```cs
noise = new FastNoiseLite(mapSeed);
noise.SetNoiseType(FastNoiseLite.NoiseType.Perlin);

noise.SetFrequency(0.01f);
noise.SetFractalLacunarity(2f);
noise.SetFractalGain(0.5f);

// this setting
noise.SetFractalType(FastNoiseLite.FractalType.FBm);
```

FBm seems to be the one that best works for the terrain generation I want

Answer (score 1):

This post is one of the few that comes up when searching for "godot FastNoise Lite" so leaving this here for a future me.
I found it hard to evaluate all the FastNoise lite arguments from within my application.

Godot's FNL actually uses this project: https://github.com/Auburn/FastNoiseLite.
That project comes with a great demo app called `PreviewApp` that lets you try out all the possible parameters in real time.
It was exactly what i needed to choose my FNL arguments.

Unfortunately `PreviewApp` has C# V3.1 dependencies which are currently awkward to install on Linux. (Probably the same on Mac?)
I had no prior C# experience.
I had to do the following:

1. Install both `aspnetcore-runtime-3.1.32-linux-x64.tar.gz` and `dotnet-sdk-3.1.426-linux-x64.tar.gz` in the same working directory. I used `~/.dotnet`.
2. Set the `DOTNET_ROOT` enviroment variable. This was `export DOTNET_ROOT=$HOME/.dotnet` for me.
3. Run `~/.dotnet/dotnet run` from the `PreviewApp` directory.

This was useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual#manual-install